# Why is my post data all null when posting with HttpClient?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to post an object from a client web app to a CRUD API for said client. I am using the following code to make the post request:

```
var respP = await _client.PostAsync("api/Persons", new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
```

And the API action method is a simple:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task Post(Person person)
{
    _db.Add(person);
    await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I have a breakpoint on `_db.Add(person);` and when that is hit, I see I do have a non-null `Person` instance in `person`, but all fields are default values, i.e. nullables are null etc.

I set up my `HttpClient` as follows:

```
_client.BaseAddress = _config["Api:Url"];
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
_client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
```

I did try making the `person` parameter type `string` to see if I could see the raw JSON, but also the the `person` param is itself null.

What am I doing wrong here?

ADDED: The `Person` class looks as below:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int PersonId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(128)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [StringLength(13)]
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }
}
```

and the actual JSON passed is:

```
{
  "PersonId": 0,
  "LastName": "df",
  "FirstName": "dfzg",
  "BirthDate": "2017-12-01T00:00:00",
  "IdNumber": "0000000000000"
}
```

Comment: I see some cerebral abscess has downvoted this question because it's off topic. What could be more about programming that I'm asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly tell the framework where to look for the incoming data to bind to the model. Use `[FromBody]` attribute on the parameter to bind data from the request body

Note: Actions which accepts user input should check the `ModelState.IsValid` property.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Person person) {
    if(ModelState.IsValid) {
        _db.Add(person);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return Ok();
    }
    return BadRequest();
}
```

Reference [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)